# Ethernet and charging cable connected cause computer freezing and screen flickering

Tags: laptop, ethernet, charging

When ethernet and charging cable both are connected the following occurs:

1. After ~1-20 minutes of usage, my computer freezes and I have to
   press the power button to shut it down.
2. My screen flickers.

I noticed even when the charging cable is almost connected (but not completely; my charging jack is loose) the issue occurs.

On only ethernet I donot face any problems.
On only wifi I donot face any problems.

The above issues occur in both Windows 10 and Linux Mint.

EDIT____________

Issue #1 - "After ~1-20 minutes of usage, my computer freezes and I have to press the power button to shut it down." only started occuring after I installed a second RAM stick

Comment: I would guess you have an earthing problem, causing static electricity build up.

Comment: Does the Ethernet cable have plastic or metal jacks?

Comment: "my charging jack is loose" all bets are off until you fix this

Comment: @grawity plastic jacks